# use table alias in subquery align with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I just started learning MySQL, and got quite confused about the table alias. When I was trying to run this query, it told me the query is invalid:

```
select customer_number 
from 
(select customer_number, count(*) as num
from orders
group by customer_number) as tmp
where num = (select max(num) in tmp)
```

I know there is a easy way to do this , I'm just confused about why my code can not work, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can rephrase this query using `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT customer_number
FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_number
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. But actually I know the right answer, just can not figure out what's wrong with the one I posted~~would you please tell me why my post is wrong?

Comment: @PengDong I would not use your current approach in MySQL because it would result in an ugly query.